# Pattern matching inside groups

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to capture inside groups, or even describe this problem. For example, a regular expression to parse markup similar to:

```
<section id="foo">
  <title>Code about Bears</title>

  <para>Words</para>

  <para><emphasis>Python Code</emphasis></para>
  <program language="py">import bears</program>

  <para><emphasis>JavaScript Code</emphasis></para>
  <program language="js">var bear = require('bears');</program>

  <section id="bar">
    <title>Code about Bear Cubs</title>

    <para>Words</para>

    <para><emphasis>Python Code</emphasis></para>
    <program language="py">import cubs</program>

    <para><emphasis>JavaScript Code</emphasis></para>
    <program language="js">var cub = require('cubs');</program>
  </section>
</section>
```

Ultimately I'd like to extract a particular language, so for Python:

```
Code about Bears: id=foo
  import bears

Code about Bear Cubs: id=bar
  import cubs
```

The difficulty is keeping `<section id="bar"/>` intact as I always end up merging its contents into `<section id="foo"/>`. Imagine it containing lot more nested sections/markup other than this simple example.

I've made two separate attempts.

[First attempt](https://regex101.com/r/pCnUI2/1) was to only extract code, and it works (fwiw these are used in PHP's preg_match_all):

```
/<emphasis>(.*) Code<\/emphasis>\s*<\/para>\s*<program ?(language="(.*)")?>\s*(.*)<\/program>/msUg
```

But that simply extracts all code and loses the section context, both in terms of section title and id.

[Second attempt](https://regex101.com/r/KLRFyi/1) was to extract sections first, but it does not work well:

```
/<section id="(.*)">\s*<title>(.*)<\/title>(.*)<\/section>/msUg
```

It matches `<section id="foo">` with the second to last `</section>` rather than separating out the inside section.

Comment: [*Don't use regex for this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), use an XML Parser.

Comment: Find `[\u0020\u0043\u0045\u0048\u004D\u004F\u0053\u0300-\u0301\u0305\u030E-\u030F\u0311-\u0312\u0314\u0316\u0319-\u031A\u031D-\u031F\u0321\u0325\u0327-\u032F\u0331-\u0332\u0334\u0336-\u0339\u033D-\u0340\u0344-\u0345\u034A\u034C-\u034F\u0356\u0358-\u0359\u035B-\u035D\u035F\u0365\u0367-\u036A\u036C-\u036F\u2013]` replace ""

Comment: TIL that this is a thing here on StackOverflow :)